# Do SmarterMail .grp date files ever change?

Tags: email, email-server

Inside of

```
\\SmarterMail\Domains\<Domain>\Users\<User>\Main\<folder>\
```

You'll find a bunch of date files, like `2012_2_4.grp`. Do these files ever change? I'd like to know because if they don't change perhaps I can run a specific rsync that doesn't update files that already exist, and speed up the process of syncing SmarterMail servers.

Any other tips on how to speed up syncing SmarterMail servers would be appreciated. I'm trying to get the server we're migrating to, to be as a current as possible prior to the switchover.

Comment: * [I also asked this question on the official forum](http://forums.smartertools.com/showthread.php/30233-Do-SmarterMail-grp-date-files-ever-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are migrating the mail server, you could run the xcopy to sync the files over even your SmarterMail services are running which it shouldn't affect the mail services or your client's access. Before you would do the last switch, stop the mail services and do a last sync and you should be on the way go for getting all the updated .grp sync over to the new server. Those files however do change as emails are move or deleted from user's Inbox or mail folders.

Comment: I'm using `rsync` over cygwin but same idea.